# How to load multiple array bytes into Bitmaps, forming a gallery

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, bitmap, out-of-memory

I m new to android programming and I am currently stuck on a big problem : Memory management.

Basically, my apps is trying to load 10 pictures (represented as `byte[]`) into 10 imageViews. The big problem is that (I think) decoding (via `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`) and having 10 bitmap at once is extremely memory consuming so I get a memory error (`OutOfMemoryError`).

My question is more technical then trying to fix my code as I want to understand how it works and fix it after understanding what's wrong.

How can you get a Bitmap to take a small amount of space on RAM at runtime?

I m only loading 10 pictures but if I had to load 50 in a scroll view (not efficient I know, gridview is better but just for the purpose of the example) would it be possible ?

I have read the android documentation but it doesn't tell me how to take less space :/ I went through all the article of this section and loaded my bitmaps properly using the code given (load a scaled down version of my image through : https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Right now, every Bitmap I load takes 20MB at runtime (way to much when limit is at around 130MB) and can I bring this down to less then 1MB by any technique?

Comment: Just resize the image. Then you need less memory. Code to make images smaller has been posted many times on this site.

Comment: Many thanks :) is it via the method Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() ?

Comment: Maybe. What i had in mind you wil find by googling for justdecodebounds.